# Update Query in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I customized an update profile page; how do I update the user details in the backend?

I tried doing this query, but its not working

```
update($table, $data, $where = '', $limit = 0, $null_values = false, $use_cache = true, $add_prefix = true)
```

Comment: you need to provide more details. How did you update the profile page? Via module? Via core modification?

Comment: @KrystianPodemski this is already done, this is my current problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74106151/apply-jquery-datatable-in-prestashop