# Apply Jquery DataTable in Prestashop

Tags: jquery, datatable, prestashop-1.7

How to i apply the jquery datatable plugin into prestashop tpl file?

i tried doing this by creating a custom tpl file

```
{extends file='customer/page.tpl'}
{block name='page_content'}
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#example').DataTable();
});
</script>
<br><br>
<div class="container">

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


</div>
{/block}
```

[here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAHUv.png)

the jquery datatable is not appearing/working

is there anyway i can call the sources properly?

should i download all the sources not to call it like this?

Comment: in your example, your loading jQuery, but... prestashop will have already loaded jQuery from another source/location? are you sure that version is compatible with data tables?

Comment: i am not sure, what datatable should i use for prestashop 1.7? @Marty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for JS code to be properly executed in Smarty templates,
you should surround it by **{literal} {/literal}** tags (see [here](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal))

Anyway that's definitely a bad practice, assuming you are developing a Prestashop module / controller, you should load your JS assets the [Prestashop way](https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/1.7/themes/getting-started/asset-management/) and keep only your table logic into the template.

Comment: what version of jquery datatable should i download for presta 1.7?